# Sub Classing NSButton

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to COCOA. I have created a cocoa application to display a button in a view.

1. Created an interface derived from NSButton.
2. I have created a window with nib file. Added a view. Created object of button interface and added to the view.

CustomButton.h

---

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomButton : NSButton
{

}
@end
```

CustomButton .mm

---

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];

    [self.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor].CGColor];
}

-(id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self)
    {
        CGSize objSize;
        objSize.height = 50;
        objSize.width = 100;
        self.frame.size       = objSize;

        CGPoint objPoint;
        objPoint.x = 10;
        objPoint.y = 10;

        self.frame.origin = objPoint;

        self.stringValue = @"Test Button";

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

MainWindow.h is the window controller class.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "CustomButton.h"

@interface MainWindow : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet NSView *m_pViewButton1;

    CustomButton*   m_pButton1;
}
@end
```

In side mainWindow.mm

---

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    NSRect objRect;
    objRect.origin = m_pViewButton1.frame.origin;
    objRect.size = m_pViewButton1.frame.size;

    [m_pViewButton1 setWantsLayer:YES];
    [m_pViewButton1.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor].CGColor];

    m_pButton1 = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:objRect];

    [m_pViewButton1 addSubview:m_pButton1];
}
```

But while i am running the application, button is not displayed.

I don't know which methode calling is missing.

Kindly help.
Thanks you all.

Regards,
Phill

Comment: Why exactly do you have to subclass `NSButton`?

Comment: I am learning cocoa. I have worked in Qt & MFC. When i need customized ui control, I create a class derived from that control class. same i was trying to do in COCOA also.

As per the documation provided by apple, it is possible. But I am missing something in my class.

Comment: How about getting a normal NSButton to add first, and then changing it to be a subclass?  Seems like you're trying to do too many things at once here, and are making it hard to debug and diagnose, as a result.  Incremental development is much easier.  Also, please: it is Cocoa, not COCOA.  Thank you.